# How to Navigate to a particular section in same page when press a button in flutter | Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I create a webpage using flutter, in top there are three buttons experience,education and contact. i created different sections for these three in this same page. The problem is when press on experience it should be need to navigate or scroll the page to that section. How can i implement this in flutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if you are making a static webpage on production level, you should consider something lightweight like vanilla js or other js framwork. Flutter is mainly used for making progressive web apps. You should take a look at loading times of flutter web projects compared to other frameworks. But if it's for a college project or something, it's fine.

Coming to your doubt, I am guessing you might be using ListView, SingleChildScrollView or GridView for your webpage. In that case you should take a look at [ScrollController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) widget.

Inititalize your controller :

ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

You can attach this controller to your ListView like this :

```
ListView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  children: [/* List of Widgets */],
                ),
```

Now in the onPressed function of your button you do the following :

```
_controller.animateTo(
  /* distance from the top of the listView where you want to animate your list to*/,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);
```